# count and display how many times data in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have one table like.count and display how many times data

```
SQL> select * from COUNT_TEST;

NAME                 ID
-------------------- ---------
A                    4
B                    3
C                    2
D                    1
```

I want output like this:

```
name     id
A        4
A        4
A        4
A        4
B        3
B        3
B        3
C        2
C        2
D        1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is id primary key and autoincrement?

Comment: No primary key and no autoincrement.

Comment: I think your output wrong in `B ->3` and `C->2` if I understand what you mean.

Comment: Now it is correct.

Comment: @GyanendraKumar You can use a CTE

Comment: @Sami can you write query?

Comment: @GyanendraKumar Recursive CTE not working in Oracle 10g

Comment: @Sami is it any another way for the oracle 10g.

Comment: You can use a Temporary table , but the answer is good

Comment: Could you write the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with COUNT_TEST(NAME, ID) as(
 select 'A',4 from DUAL union all
 select 'B',3 from DUAL union all
 select 'C',2 from DUAL union all
 select 'D',1 from DUAL
)
  select NAME, ID
    from COUNT_TEST
 connect by NAME=prior NAME and level<=ID
     and prior DBMS_RANDOM.value is not null;
```

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/LSSQY96074) for it.

Comment: This query is working fine.could you write another query?

Comment: @GyanendraKumar . . . You should accept this answer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ...I have already accepted this answer.But i want to know another way.That's why i asked.

Comment: @GyanendraKumar another way - needs table (or subquery select 1 union select 2 union ... select max(ID)) with numbers from 1 to max(ID) and join with this table on number<=ID

Comment: @GyanendraKumar - why do you want another query?

Comment: @Mike Writing the query some another way or whatever query you have written before could you write more simple?

Comment: @GyanendraKumar Easier not where. Other ways are not universal. http://rextester.com/NWPO74906

Comment: @Mike how do you write the query when there are 100 records in the table

Comment: @HarishBarma `connect by` generate infinity numbers